# Help for understanding Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: integration

Why is it that according to Leibniz Integral Rule, we cannot take derivative inside integration when both derivative and integration are over the same variable?

For example: Let's say we have $f(x,t)$.

derivative w.r.t. $t$ {integration of $f(x,t)$ w.r.t. $x$} is possible.

I want to understand why derivative w.r.t. $x$ {integration of $f(x,t)$ w.r.t. $x$} is not possible.

Could anyone please help me get insight on this?

**EDIT:**
Also, I would like to learn why, according to Leibniz Integral Rule, we cannot take derivative inside the integration in the latter case of derivative w.r.t. $x$?

Answer (score 0):

##### Make sure you understand the effect of "integrating out" a variable

It's possible to do that integral, but it gives you a value of zero.  If you have a definite integral of $f(x,t)$ with respect to $x$, and the range of integration does not depend on $x$, then the resulting function is *not* a function of $x$ --- when $x$ is "integrated out" you get a function of $t$ (and the range of integration).  Consequently, for any range of integration $\mathcal{A}$ that does not depend on $x$, you have:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \int \limits_{\mathcal{A}} f(x,t) \ dx = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} H(t,\mathcal{A}) = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! My intuitive understanding of integration was area under the curve in the range of integration with x-axis containing variable being integrated. But as you have mentioned that the range of integration does not depend on x, I am confused. Could you please help me better understand the "integrating out" concept? @Ben

Comment: I have edited the post with an additional question. Could you please share your knowledge regarding that too? It can be really helpful for me. @Ben

Comment: My existing answer essentially answers your question --- the derivative of the integral is zero, but if you were to take the derivative inside the equation this would change the result.  Hence, you can't do it.

Comment: I do not understand how integration is done when range of integration does not depend on x (i.e. variable over which integration is done). Is there any rule associated with it? How did ∫A f(x,t) dx become H(t,A)? Could you please help me understand this? @Ben

Comment: All I mean here by $H(t,\mathcal{A})$ is that the integral gives some value that is a function of $t$ and $\mathcal{A}$ (the name $H$ is arbitrary).  Try a few examples of integrating a bivariate function over a range for one of its variables and you should see that the result is no longer a function of the variable-of-integration you started with.